# dompdf not work in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I get this error, when using Zend Framework v2.4: Call to undefined method Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ViewManager::getResolver() in /../../../demo/vendor/dino/dompdf-module/src/DOMPDFModule/Mvc/Service/ViewPdfRendererFactory.php on line 39 But there is no `getResolver` method in `viewmanager`. I am using zend framework 2.4/

```
Can you help me to solve this?

This is included in vender.

<?php

use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;

This is controller action

public function generatepdfAction(){
    //  $pdf1 = new Zendpdf\PdfDocument();
    echo "bbb";
    $pdf = new PdfModel();
        $pdf->setOption('filename', 'monthly-report'); // Triggers PDF download, automatically appends ".pdf"
        $pdf->setOption('paperSize', 'a4'); // Defaults to "8x11"
        $pdf->setOption('paperOrientation', 'landscape'); // Defaults to "portrait"

        // To set view variables
        $pdf->setVariables(array(
          'message' => 'Hello'
        ));

        return $pdf;
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your post, give us your code, and tell us where this error is raised? It is unclear...

Comment: In error log this error show as fatal error

Comment: This error when use 
use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;
 got

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a error in your code. This is a known issue as you can see on https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule/issues/37

There is also a pull request for that issue. I solved this with creating my own DOMPDFModule with the changes of [this commit](https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule/pull/36/commits/21fd356c8d79c111116555fba0ef94bd24594d95), because it seems that there won't be an update of DOMPDFModule soon.

Another possibility would be using an older version of zend-mvc, because the issue appears since zend-mvc 2.7. Just use

"zendframework/zend-mvc": "~2.6.3"

in your composer.json and the the DOMPDFModule will work again. But this should be only a temporarily solution if you want to use new features of the Zend Framework and its modules in the future.